# Raise events from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I want to call methods from `ActivityFragment` class, but I suspect that I don't fully understand the way of this `ActionBar Fragments` works...

This is my main code for class that creates `ActionBar` tabs:

```
public class OrdersActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Nowe")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabNewFragment>(
                    this, "new", TabNewFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Wykonywane")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabInProgFragment>(
                    this, "in_progress", TabInProgFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Archiwum")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabArchFragment>(
                    this, "archived", TabArchFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}
```

`TabListener` looks exactly like this one: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

This is `Fragment` class:

```
public class TabNewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_new, container, false);
        return mainView;
    }
}
```

And my `FragmentActivity` class:

```
public class TabNewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

Button mAddNew;
private ProductItemAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_new);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"aaaaa",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    productTable = msc.getTable(Products.class);

    mAddNew=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    mAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addProductItem(v);
        }
    });
    mAdapter = new ProductItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row_product_list);
    ListView listViewProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProducts);
    listViewProducts.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

public void addProductItem(View view) {

    Products item = new Products();
    //more code....
}
```

the `activity_tab_new.xml` looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="275dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="azure.holdersystem.View.OrdersActivityTabs.TabNewActivity">        

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_1"
        android:text="Dodaj produkt"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>.....
```

Everything works but no events are rised when I click the button or even this simple Toast does not show up...

What am I doing wrong?

### edit.

**well, it was very simply... just removing FragmentActivity and add metods to fragment class.**

Comment: Your code is actionbar activity is ok but what is this TabNewActivity

when it is launched ?

Comment: this is an activity for `layout.activity_tab_new`